Error al tratar hacer rebase o cherry-pick por sobreescritura de archivos al hacer checkout
Tengo una rama en git con base en la rama dev con el siguiente grafo:
* 5 -> rama1
* 4 -> fix3
* 3 -> fix2
* 2 -> fix1
* 1 -> dev

Pero quiero hacerle un rebase sobre dev para squashear los commits con el commit message "fix", así que:
$ git switch rama1 && git rebase -i dev
Y editamos el todo-file algo asi:
p 2 fix1
s 3 fix2
s 4 fix3
s 5 rama1

Y cuando lo cierro, tengo el siguiente error:

error: your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Cuando, ni tengo archivos en el workspace, ni tengo archivos en el stagging area.
Y para asegurarme de eso, hago git reset rama1 --hard, asegurandome de que no tengo nada en el workspace. Incluso git status no saca ningún resultado. También, por si las dudas, hago git stash clear, pero tengo el mismo error.
Una cosa que se me ocurrió sólo porque si, fue que creara otra rama llamada rama2 basada en dev, y aplicar poco a poco cada commit entre "dev" y "rama1".
git switch -c rama2 dev
git cherry-pick 2
git cherry-pick 3
git cherry-pick 4
git cherry-pick 5

Y en uno de esos pasos intermedios con cherry-pick, tengo el siguiente error similar al anterior:

error: your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Y de nuevo, no tengo archivos en el workspace ni en el stagging area.
Lo que investigué fue que quizás haya un problema de salto de líneas, para lo que apliqué durante ese error lo siguiente:
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.eol lf
git add --update --renormalize

Pero sucede lo mismo.
Al final, terminé solo copiando los archivos que modifiqué en rama1 hacia una rama nueva basada en dev:
git switch -c one-commit dev
git restore --source rama1 -- $(git diff dev rama1 --name-only | tr "\n" " ")
git add $(git diff dev rama1 --name-only | tr "\n" " ")
git commit -am "etc"

Tengo la fuerte sospecha de que esto tiene que ver con los finales de línea ya que me encuentro dentro de Windows, programo en IntelliJ, pero todo lo de git lo ejecuto a través de Cygwin.

Me van a ayudar, o nel?
